# How to rewrite url after proxy_pass for loading ressource file (css / image)

Tags: nginx

i have a server with 3 webapps on the follow url :

- Jenkins (http://localhost:7000/)
- Tomcat (http://localhost:8080/)
- Sonar (http://localhost:9000/)

i want to rewrite all of those url for looking like this :

- http://localhost/jenkins/
- http://localhost/tomcat/
- http://localhost/sonar/

so i edited my nginx.conf :

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /sonar/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/; 
        }

        location /tomcat/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        }

        location /jenkins/ { 
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/; 
        }
    }
}
```

Cause these file is located on localhost/appName/css or image and the url who there are call are localhost/css or image. Some one could tell me how to rewrite all of this url ?

Comment: Try it with `$host` instead of `localhost`. Also, what is the current status? Any errors, log output, etc…?

Comment: $host on server_name change nothing and no log. :/

Comment: Take a look at the nginx docs and the tag on ServerFault for how to pump up your logs. Also you can always `return 200 $request_filename;`. This [link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/capturing-5xx-errors-debug-server/) to Nginx blog might be of some help as well.